# Adding CSS to GridView in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

I am trying to style my GridView object but I can't seem to get it to use the CSS class. I am creating the GridViews dynamically, so they are all created in code-behind. I have tried the following and nothing seems to work.

```
for (...)
{
 GridView gv = new GridView();
 gv.CssClass = "aclass";
 gv.Attributes.Add("class", "aclass");
}
```

and also in the RowDataBound event:

```
foreach (row in gv)
e.Row.Cells[i].CssClass = "aClass";
```

and yet I still cannot style my data. Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: In which stage of the page lifecycle are you creating the gridview? `Page load`, `Init`?

Comment: I am doing it in PageLoad

Comment: Try moving that code to the `Page_Init` method. Dynamic controls should not be created on the page load, because of the page lifecycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "controlbackcolor";
            e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "controlbackcolor";
        }
    }
```

this should work but you need to make sure that the css classes are put in the right place or linked.. otherwise you wont get the style applied

Your Css class declaration should look something like the following in head tag or link:

.controlbackcolor
        {
            background: green;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: White;
        }

Comment: Can you elaborate where it needs to be? I have a Site.Css page and I was under the impression I can put it anywhere in there. Thanks

Comment: If you have started from New Web Site template and using the Site master page, then CSS classes you put in site.css should be available to any page.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to assign CssClass, as you are doing. And then control style using selectors like this:

**Codehind**

```
MyGridView.CssClass = "aclass";
```

**CSS**

```
.aclass{Border: 1px solid lighgray;}
.aclass tr td {background:green; font-weight:bold; color: white}
```

Gridview is rendered as normal table in HTML, so you can do this on CSS side to reduce code behind load.

Answer (score 1):

> Bootstrap class can also be added in code behind like

```
protected void gvEmpContactsHistory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string val = Convert.ToDateTime(gvEmpContactsHistory.SelectedDataKey.Value).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        GetEmployeeDetail(val);

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvEmpContactsHistory.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowIndex == gvEmpContactsHistory.SelectedIndex)
            {
                row.ToolTip = string.Empty;
                row.Attributes.Add("class", "btn-success");
            }
            else
            {
                row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
                row.Attributes.Add("class", "btn-outline-success");
            }
        }
    }
```